# List files and their size inside a zip file in JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to list, a list of files answering a specific pattern ("*.xz" in my case) from within a zip file.

The structure of my archive is this:

```
repo_name:
 folder0:
   inner_folder:
     my_archive.zip
       my_archive_folder:
         username1_folder:
          tar0.xz
          tar1.xz
            ...
```

I'm using the following AQL (Artifact Query Language):

```
archive.entries.find({
 "archive.item.repo": {
    "$eq": "repo_name"
 },
 "archive.item.name": {
    "$eq": "my_archive.zip"
},
"archive.entry.name": {
    "$match": "*.xz"
},
"archive.entry.path": {
    "$match": "my_archive_folder/username1_folder/*"
},
"archive.item.path": {
    "$eq": "folder0/inner_folder"
}
})
```

I have multiple folders inside my repository, and I want to be able to get all of the files answering to `*.xz` to all of the usernames inside `my_archive.zip`.

The weird thing is - this query works only to some of the folders, even though they're all in the same structure!

Any idea what I'm missing?

I'm using version 7.27.9 on SaaS.

Comment: Please provide more details, e.g. Artifactory version, saas / on-prem.
For example, since Artifactory 7.15.3 the archive indexing feature is disabled by default (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.15.3). So some of the archives might not be indexed and therefor are not returned by the query.

Comment: @yinon Thanks for replying
Its a SAAS, version - 7.27.9. Is there a way to activate it?

Comment: Not sure if and how it can be enabled in SaaS. You can contact JFrog support.